# Memory usage metric identifier Google Compute Engine

Tags: memory, google-compute-engine, autoscaling, metric

I have installed the monitoring agent in my instance group disk. I need to autoscale instances based on memory usage, however when I am going to configure the target metric in GCE web console I miss the memory usage metric identifier. Which is the missing identifier or how can I autoscale my group based on memory usage?

[image]

Comment: It seems there is no GCE monitoring metric for memory. You can open a PIT case for this feature at:  https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list

Comment: GCE now has a memory metric. See Carlos's answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991246/google-cloud-platform-how-to-monitor-memory-usage-of-vm-instances for answer.